# Gradle Module Build Order

Tags: android, gradle, build, module

I have a Gradle root project `P` with two subprojects `P:foo` and `P:bar`. Naturally, Gradle builds them in alphabetical order: `bar`, `foo`. But I need `foo` to be built first when I say `gradle build` in the `P` root directory. This is because `bar` depends on the AAR (Android library) artifact that `foo` publishes to the local Maven repository. Both `bar` and `foo` are such Android-library projects.

This looks like an easy problem, but I can't figure it out. I read about `evaluationDependsOn`, so in `bar/build.gradle`, I say in the first line: `evaluationDependsOn "foo:"`. Alas, this does not seem to have any effect. Is this Gradle feature broken in the end?

Using `compile project`, I could enforce `foo` to be built first, but that would add the compiled classes directly to `bar`, which I don't want.

So I'm stuck. I could rename `foo` to `aaa_foo` and all my problems would be gone, but I hesitate to call that a solution.

Comment: "Using compile project, I could enforce foo to be built first, but that would add the compiled classes directly to bar, which I don't want" -- only if `bar` is an application module, and in that case you should want to have the `foo` classes in it. If `bar` is a library module, `foo` classes will not go into the `bar` AAR.

Comment: If I say `compile project`, Gradle tries to link the library twice (once for `compile project`, and once for the Maven-repository dependency), and I get the error message "Error: more than one library with package name 'com.acme.frob'".

Comment: Then your Gradle build scripts have issues. Since your question does not include them, I cannot tell you exactly where you are going wrong. But almost every one of my CWAC libraries has two modules: the library and a demo project that links to the library. Sometimes a project has two libraries or two demos. They all work using `compile project()` (for library-to-library dependencies within the same overall project) or `debugCompile project()` (for demo-to-library dependencies, where I use `releaseCompile` to confirm that I can pull from my artifact repository).

Comment: I updated the question text to make this more clear. Both projects are library projects---they both push to the local Maven repo.

Comment: My [CWAC-NetSecurity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) library has two library modules (`netsecurity` and `netsecurity-netcipher`). Project references work fine. I did make a mistake in my previous comment, as I do use `debugCompile project()`, instead of `compile project()`, to express how `netsecurity-netcipher` depends upon `netsecurity`.

Comment: Okay, I see you were in a very similar situation. I copied the trick from your Gradle file. Now, for the Debug flavor, things are compiled in correct order, but for the Release flavor, the problem persists: `bar` Release is compiled against a possibly outdated version of `foo` in the Maven repo, then `foo` Release is compiled. I guess you don't notice a problem because `netsecurity-netcipher` comes alphabetically after `netsecurity`. I mean, all I want is to change the default module build order. What is this `evaluationDependsOn` thing about? Why is this so hard?

Comment: "the problem persists: bar Release is compiled against a possibly outdated version of foo in the Maven repo" -- when you push a new `foo` to the repo, update `releaseCompile` on `bar` to use the new version number of `foo`. "I guess you don't notice a problem because netsecurity-netcipher comes alphabetically after netsecurity." -- no, I do not notice a problem because I use version numbers.

Comment: I don't want to increase the Maven version number for every turnaround build. Whenever I hit "Build" in Android Studio, I push to the local repo, that's the way I work. It's even worse: When I increase the version number of the lib I depend upon, Gradle doesn't find the artifact because it hasn't been published yet. I just need a way to have Gradle first build `foo`, then `bar` ...

Comment: "I don't want to increase the Maven version number for every turnaround build" -- which is why the `debug` builds work off of just the project reference. You only have to deal with version numbers for `release` builds. "Whenever I hit "Build" in Android Studio, I push to the local repo, that's the way I work" -- then I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot for your time and patience, I really appreciate!

Answer (score 19):

Okay, so let me answer this question myself. I think I found a decent solution.

A *project dependency* in Gradle is usually expressed by means of `compile project`, which not only builds the other project but also adds the other project's classes to the classpath of the current project. If you only want to make sure another project is built before yours, you can use a *task dependency*.

In my Android environment, in `bar/build.gradle`, I have

```
preBuild.dependsOn ":foo:build"
```

and all is well. Now `foo` is always built before `bar`.

Comment: I just spent a tons of time doing this: project build order.
Thank you...
There are a lot of material about how to reorder of task in Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life!

Comment: Ha Ha Ha, tanks a lot. and it works.