# Gradle Module Build Order 2

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have and Android Gradle project with many modules (only AARs, no APP).

Because Google does not support fat AARs, I need to do the repackaging myself (I tried multiple fat AAR Gradle plugins but none of it is actually working, support did not help me at all).

So I have to write the repackaging myself (as a Groovy script, directly into my Gradle build system).

For that I need to:

- Build many AARs - these are multiple Gradle modules
- Repackage all those AARs into the one big AAR - this is a special Gradle module (all the AARs above are set as the implementation dependency to this AAR)
- Then obfuscate everything using DexGuard (no ProGuard/R8 - these are too weak)

The repackaging works fine to me. BUT...

If I execute this to ensure the clean release build:

```
./gradlew clean :MbiSdkLibrary:assembleRelease
```

It first cleans everything and then tries to build my FAT library.

The problem is that the MbiSdkLibrary AAR build starts in parallel with the build of dependency AARs, while the build of the other AARs is NOT fully completed yet. In other words, Gradle seems to ignore the dependencies when determining the build order.

Subsequently the repackaging of MbiSdkLibrary (the final fat AAR) fails randomly (it is a race) on the missing AAR from the other (parallel) builds.

Of course I can achieve the build working this way (I tested, it works just fine):

- Build the dependency AARs first with a separate gradle command
- Build the final fat AAR afterwards (without the clean task)

But that solution sounds stupid to me, I believe Gradle cannot be that limited to be unable to do such a simple thing properly...

I also Googled a lot and tried a few workarounds, including e.g. this one:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42349993/8823423
- It does NOT work to me for some reason (the task dependencies to other Gradle modules do not work to me)

My question is related to this question: [Gradle Module Build Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329484/gradle-module-build-order).

Sorry, for some reason, I am not allowed to communicate there so I am forced to flood SO with another (very similar) question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to HACK the problem using the task of GradleBuild type.

But it made the build 5 times slower and consuming a lot of more memory.

This is my method

```
// Note: This method is a bit hacky solution:
// - It creates a child Gradle build which can easily cause OOM error
// Awaiting response for the Gradle related question:
// - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624688/gradle-module-build-order-2
// - Hopefully someone knows better way hot to do this properly

def aarDependencies_setupModuleDependencies(task) {
    String buildType
    if (task.name == 'preBuild') {
        buildType = ''
    } else if (task.name == 'preDebugBuild') {
        buildType = 'Debug'
    } else if (task.name == 'preReleaseBuild') {
        buildType = 'Release'
    } else {
        return
    }
    List<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>()
    project.ext.REPACKAGING__PROJECT_DEP.each { dirFn ->
        String moduleName = dirFn[1]
        String taskToRun = ":$moduleName:assemble$buildType"
        taskList.add(taskToRun)
    }
    task.dependsOn tasks.create(name: "buildDependenciesFor${buildType}", type: GradleBuild) {
        dir "../../"
        buildFile 'build.gradle'
        setTasks(taskList)
        doFirst {
            aarDependencies_log("Ensuring dependencies for build type '${buildType}' are available...")
        }
        doLast {
            aarDependencies_log("Ensuring dependencies for build type '${buildType}' are available: DONE")
        }
    }
}
```